# How can I reproduce the result of DimensionReduction?

Tags: matrix, numerics, linear-algebra, dimension-reduction

In the help document of DimensionReduction, there is some sample codes as below:-

```
dr = DimensionReduction[{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 5}, {3, 5, 8}, {4, 5, 8.5}}]
dr[{6, 7, 14}]
```

Result:-

```
{-5.27725, 0.304718}
```

How can I reproduce the result? I used the following codes to obtain the eigenvectors, but have no idea on how to continue:-

```
matrix = N[{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 5}, {3, 5, 8}, {4, 5, 8.5}}]
X=Covariance@Standardize@matrix
eigenVectors = Eigenvectors@X
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two-dimensional reduced space is the row space of `eigenVectors[[1 ;; 2]]`. The orthogonal projector onto that space is `Transpose[eigenVectors[[1 ;; 2]]].eigenVectors[[1 ;; 2]]`. And `dr[[1, "Model", "Matrix"]]` is identical to `Transpose[eigenVectors[[1 ;; 2]]]`.

Alternatively, you get the same matrix from singular value decomposition without calculating the covariance matrix (which might lead to inaccurate results due to high condition number),

```
{U, Σ, W} = SingularValueDecomposition[Standardize@matrix];
W[[All, 1 ;; 2]]
```

**Edit**

Still not a perfect answer but I figured out what `dr[dr[u], "OriginalVectors"]` seems to do:

```
matrix = N[{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 5}, {3, 5, 8}, {4, 5, 8.5}}];
shift = Mean[matrix]
centereddata = matrix - ConstantArray[shift, Length[matrix]];
variances = Variance@centereddata;
scales = 1/Sqrt[variances];
standardizeddata = centereddata.DiagonalMatrix[scales];
(* standardizeddata == Standardize[matrix] *)

{U, Σ, W} = SingularValueDecomposition[standardizeddata];

embedding = W[[All, 1 ;; 2]];
sampling = Transpose[W[[All, 1 ;; 2]]];
projector = embedding.sampling;

Dot[projector, (u - shift) scales]/scales + shift

dr = DimensionReduction[matrix];
reduced = dr[u];
dr[reduced, "OriginalVectors"]
```

> {6.14743, 7.48357, 12.8791}
>
> {6.14743, 7.48357, 12.8791}

My guess was that `dr[u]` equals `Dot[sampler, (u - shift) scales]` but I have been proven wrong. Anyways, the internal representation of the data does not really matter. You may equivalently use

```
reducer = u \[Function] Dot[sampling, (u - shift) scales];
reconstructor = v \[Function] Dot[embedding, v]/scales + shift;
```

for dimension reduction.

Comment: Thanks and noted your edit. So what does `dr[{1, 0}, "OriginalVectors"]` and `dr[{0, 1}, "OriginalVectors"]` mean? They are different to the eigen vectors...

Comment: Hm. That's hard to tell since I do not understand the coordinates that Mathematica uses within the two-dimensional affine subspace onto which we project. I think you and me as users are not supposed to know what `dr[{1, 0}, "OriginalVectors"]` should actually mean; we are expected to use it like `dr[dr[u], "OriginalVectors"]` or `dr[u, "ReconstructedVectors"]` (which is equivalent). But I am not exactly sure. Sorry.

Comment: Many thanks for your help!

Comment: You are very welcome!